# Syntax Error in Dreamweaver with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dreamweaver

I am working with Symfony for the first time, and am attempting to create a new form class. As per the example in the documentation, I have this as part of my code:

```
$builder
    ->add('title')
    ->add('summary', TextareaType::class)
    ->add('content', TextareaType::class)
    ->add('authorEmail', EmailType::class)
    ->add('publishedAt', DateTimeType::class)
;
```

This is giving me a syntax error on the third through sixth lines. The syntax error can be fixed by removing "::class" from the types of form inputs, but I feel like those would be necessary for the code to be operational?

Do I need to suppress the syntax errors on Dreamweaver (I mean I guess I could just live with the syntax error, but it would be nice to have it resolved), or is there a way I can have Dreamweaver recognize this as correct code (or is the code incorrect)?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the "::class" part actually do? I don't think I've seen it before.

Comment: Not sure what the class part does, but the "::" is a scope resolution operator - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: `::class` returns the fully qualified name of the class. The equivalent of calling `get_class(new TextareaType)`.

Answer (score 0):

The Type classes expect an attr array by default (although no required)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/textarea.html

eg.

```
$builder->add('body', TextareaType::class, array(
    'attr' => array('class' => 'tinymce'),
));
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the syntax error on dreamweaver unfortunately - it's not that the code is creating errors on the website, it's that the errors are being flagged on the text editor.